# How to use jQuery .live on this plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm loading some content via ajax and need to use the `live()` function. Since the following plugin has properties to set how do you set it up to use `live()`?

```
$(function () {
        $("#book-wrapper .books").hoverIntent({
            over: enter,
            out: leave,
            interval: 200
        });
    });
    function enter() { $(this).animate({ width: '+=115px' }, 350, 'swing'); $(".slide-out", this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 450, 'swing'); }
    function leave() { $(this).animate({ width: '-=115px' }, 350, 'swing'); $(".slide-out", this).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 450, 'swing'); }
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the `hoverIntent` method to all new `.books`??

Comment: @philwinkle, yes, on page load there will be no such elements with class `.books`. They will loaded via ajax, then I need them to react to hoverIntent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your above clarification - you may not actually need `live`... as `bind` does this for you.  Some other plugins exist that do this as well, including `livequery`

```
$(function(){
  $('html').bind('myhoverintent',function(){
        $('#book-wrapper .books').hoverIntent({
            over: enter,
            out: leave,
            interval: 200
        }); //fixed syntax error
});

//then, later in your method that adds .books:

$('html').append('<div class="books">test</div').trigger('myhoverintent');
```

Even simpler would be if your method to add books comes as a result of a jQuery ajax method, you could just re-call your original selector on the `success` method of `$.ajax`

Comment: @philwinkle, the part inside the ready function causes no javascript to work in the app.

Comment: I actually found a syntax error and updated. See some pseudo code example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/philwinkle/XQaRN/

Comment: @philwinkle, I didn't even think about putting it in the `$.ajax` success function, duh :/

Comment: @philwinkle I am afraid your code would lead to multiple instance of hoverIntent to be generated on each .books. The problem is on the line $('#book-wrapper .books').hoverIntent() as it creates the hoverIntent effect on every .books including already existed ones. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @quincy you might be right - this is a working model. He may want to unset hoverintent first... however it seems as though he's gone ahead and put the functionality/selector into the success portion of his ajax call.

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
        $("#book-wrapper .books").live("hoverIntent",function(){
            over: enter,
            out: leave,
            interval: 200
        });
    });
    function enter() { $(this).animate({ width: '+=115px' }, 350, 'swing'); $(".slide-out", this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 450, 'swing'); }
    function leave() { $(this).animate({ width: '-=115px' }, 350, 'swing'); $(".slide-out", this).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 450, 'swing'); }
```

Comment: the parameters inside the function will think they are variables with your syntax, this won't work.

Comment: @Nick . . Yea, didn't notice about the parameters inside the function. Sorry :)